# Undefined when calling id in HTML 5 input

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a page that includes an x amount of items and each of these include a HTML 5 input.

When user changes the value of the input the server gets invoked via an AJAX call. The server then responds with JSON that includes an array of items that include a quantity value. If the returned quantity value is different from the one that was sent to the server (value of input) I need to change the input box value so that it is equal to the returned quantity value.

My problem is that I am getting an undefined in the alert instead of the id, could someone please tell me why, thank you in advance!

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
//loop through JSON returned items array
for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
     var id = data.items[i].id;
     var title = data.items[i].title
     var price = data.items[i].price
     var quantity = data.items[i].quantity
     var image = data.items[i].image

     //output JSON to HTML
     $("#result").append("<div class='column left'><img src="+ image + "width=100 height=100 style=padding:20px></div><div class='column middle' >" + " " + title + " " + price + "</div><div class='column right' ><input id='" + id + "' type=number min=1 max=10 step=1 value="+quantity+" maxlength=2 size=2 />&nbsp;<br><a data-id='" + id + "' href=# id='remove'>Remove</a></div>");

     //load subtotal when page loads
     $('#subtotal').html(data.items_subtotal_price);
}
```

**JSON**

```
//QUANTITY update
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
      $.ajax({
          url: "https://example.com/cart/change.json",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
             id: $(this).attr('id'),
             quantity : $(this).val()
          },
          //JSON response
          success: function(data) {
             console.log(data); //formatted JSON data
             $('#subtotal').html(data.items_subtotal_price); //set subtotal from JSON

            //1.  loop through JSON items for id >> get returned quantity value where id matches id of input box
            //2.  if quantity returned is not equal to the quantity sent then it's been disallowed by the server >> update input box value to equal returned value
            // getting UNDEFINED - 
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: store `$(this)` in variable and use in ajax success as `var _t = $(this);` `alert(_t.attr('id'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `success()` function, `this` refers the success() function but not the HTML element `keyup mouseup` binding function. To get `keyup mouseup` function instance you can add another variable `self = this` before writing the `AJAX`. Now, inside success function you can access that `self` reference to get the `ID` attribute. Example:

```
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        // .....
        // ....
        success: function(data) {
            alert($(self).attr('id'));
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively you can bind `this` reference to success function using [***Function.prototype.bind()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function without second var `self`. For instance

```
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    $.ajax({
        // other properties
        success: (function(data) {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        }).bind(this)
    });
});
```